# Magento 2 handle tag explained

Tags: magento2, layout, update-handle

1.Why is there an update tag inside checkout_item_price_renderers.xml with the same file name?

```
<update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
```

2.The update tag will look for the file with the name that is specified inside handle property and will merge the current xml file with the one indicated by update tag? Is that correct?